# Display a combobox list driven from property changed event in a MvvM model

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I am fairly new to MVVM and I am writing a search view in my model that contains 2 combo boxes. I need to display various lists in my second combo box based on my first combo box selection. Combo box 1 looks like this

```
<ComboBox Margin="103,6,0,24" Name="cmbCriteria" DisplayMemberPath="SetCriteria" Grid.Column="1">
                        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                            <CompositeCollection>
                                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={x:Static model:SearchCriteriaStaicData.MyStaicCriteriaList}}" />
                            </CompositeCollection>
                        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                    </ComboBox>
```

This displays data from my code behind

```
{
        public string SetCriteria { get; set; }

    }    
    public class SearchCriteriaStaicData
    {
        public static List<SearchCriteriaList> MyStaicCriteriaList
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<SearchCriteriaList>()
                {
                    new SearchCriteriaList {SetCriteria = "Date Range"},
                    new SearchCriteriaList {SetCriteria = "Gateway"},
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

What I would like to do is if the selected combo box value is Date Range then
my second combo box displays the list in my SearchDateOperatorStaticData class

```
public class SearchDateOperatorStaticData
   {
       public static List<SearchOperatorLists> DateStaicOperatorList
       {
           get 
           {
               return new List<SearchOperatorLists>()
               {
                   new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "Today"},
                   new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "Between"},
                   new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "Last Month"},
               };
           }
       }     
   }
```

Or if Gateway is selected from the first combo box the second combo box displays a list from the SearchGatewayOperatorStaticData

```
public class SearchGatewayOperatorStaticData
   {
       public static List<SearchOperatorLists> GatewayStaicOperatorList
       {
           get
           {
               return new List<SearchOperatorLists>()
               {
                   new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "Email"},
                   new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "RDP"},
                   new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "Web"},
                   new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "Other"},
               };
           }
       }  
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you added the **mvvm** tag, I suggest you to follow the MVVM pattern and move the logic to the view model.

Create a view model that will contain your collections:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly List<SearchOperatorLists> dateOperatorList = new List<SearchOperatorLists> 
    {
        new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "Today"},
        new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "Between"},
        new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "Last Month"} 
    };

    private readonly List<SearchOperatorLists> gatewayOperatorList = new List<SearchOperatorLists> 
    {
        new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "Email"},
        new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "RDP"},
        new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "Web"},
        new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "Other"} 
    };

    private SearchCriteriaList selectedCriteriaList;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.CriteriaList = new ObservableCollection<SearchCriteriaList> 
        {
            new SearchCriteriaList {SetCriteria = "Date Range"},
            new SearchCriteriaList {SetCriteria = "Gateway"} 
        };

        this.OperatorList = new ObservableCollection<SearchOperatorLists>();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<SearchCriteriaList> CriteriaList { get; private set; }

    public SearchCriteriaList SelectedCriteriaList 
    {
        get { return this.selectedCriteriaList; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.selectedCriteriaList)
            {
                this.selectedCriteriaList = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCriteriaList");
                this.UpdateOperators();
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<SearchOperatorLists> OperatorList { get; private set; }

    private void UpdateOperators()
    {
        this.OperatorList.Clear();

        if (this.SelectedCriteriaList == this.CriteriaList[0])
        {
            foreach (SearchOperatorLists item in this.dateOperatorList)
            {
                this.OperatorList.Add(item);
            }
        }
        else if (this.SelectedCriteriaList == this.CriteriaList[1])
        {
            foreach (SearchOperatorLists item in this.gatewayOperatorList)
            {
                this.OperatorList.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that the view model contains a property `SelectedCriteriaList`, which is bound to current selection item of the combobox. When this value changes (e.g. via user selection in combobox), your view model does its job and calls the `UpdateOperators()` method. This method will update the `OperatorList` collection so its items correspond the selected criteria.

Your view should then use the bindings:

```
<ComboBox 
    DisplayMemberPath="SetCriteria" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding CriteriaList}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCriteriaList, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<ComboBox 
    DisplayMemberPath="OperatorName" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding OperatorList}"/>
```